# Сложить целое и None

Tags: python

Как можно складывать, если числа могут быть None? Постоянно проверять через if или есть какой-нибудь другой способ?

Comment: typeOfNone = type(None) , None == None

Comment: Объекты в питоне могут являться не только числами и `None` :)

Comment: я не пойму чем проверка с if не подходит, все равно вы или делаете проверку или нет. Другого варианта нет. Или вы хотите сложить None и число, и вы спрашиваете как это сделать?

Comment: понятно, думал может какая-то волшебная функция есть)))).

Comment: 'if var is None' ну или тернарный оператор

Comment: number = None , 
sum = number if 1 + number else 'не складывается'

Answer (score 5):

Есть волшебная функция. в модуле numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = [None, None, 8, None,6, None, None, 9, None, None, None, 3, None]
print(np.nansum(np.array(a, dtype=float)))
```

> 26.0

Answer (score 3):

Я могу предложить 2 однострочных варианта

```
my_list = [1, None, 2, None, 3, None, "asdasd", '123123']
# Если нам нужны только числа
new_list = [value for value in my_list if isinstance(value, int)]
print(new_list)
# Если нужно проверить что строка это число
new_list = [ int(value) for value in my_list if isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, str) == True and value.isdigit()]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

Да постоянно проверять через if, как указано в дзен питона. Создание альтернативной структуры без None, на мой взгляд не целесообразно, так как при больших размерах влечёт увеличение расхода оперативной памяти. Так же есть вариант использования try-except, но это замедлит выполнение программы.

Answer (score 2):

Да, в любом случае вам придется как то избавляться от None: либо сразу почистить список, либо по мере прохождения списка проверять на тип.

```
my_list = [1, None, 2, None, 3, None]
countable_values = [value for value in my_list if value]
sum = sum(countable_values) if countable_values else None
```

или

```
my_list = [1, None, 2, None, 3, None]
sum = 0
for value in my_list:
    if value:
        sum += value
```

Answer (score 2):

Дополню комментарий @ganz

```
    import datetime


    my_list = [большой массив из int, None, str]
    print("Используем итератор")
    time_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    # Если нужно проверить что строка это число
    new_list = [ int(value) for value in my_list if isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, str) == True and value.isdigit()]
    time_end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f"Время работы: {time_end - time_start}\nИсходный размер массива: {len(my_list)}\nФинальный размер массива: {len(new_list)}")
    print("------------------------------")
    print("Используем try-except")
    new_list1 = []
    time_start1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in my_list:
      try:
        new_list1.append(int(i))
      except:
        pass
    time_end1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f"Время работы: {time_end1 - time_start1}\nИсходный размер массива: {len(my_list)}\nФинальный размер массива: {len(new_list1)}")
    print("------------------------------")
    print("Создание структуры без None")
    time_start2 = datetime.datetime.now()
    list_not_none = []
    for i in my_list:
        if i:
          list_not_none.append(i)
    new_list2 = []
    for j in list_not_none:
      if isinstance(j, int):
        new_list2.append(j)
      elif isinstance(j, str):
        if j.isdigit():
          new_list2.append(int(j))
    time_end2 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f"Время работы: {time_end2 - time_start2}\nИсходный размер массива: {len(my_list)}\nФинальный размер массива: {len(new_list2)}")
```

Результаты работы:

1 Запуск:

```
Используем итератор
Время работы: 0:00:00.000997
Исходный размер массива: 14520
Финальный размер массива: 7260
===============================
Используем try-except
Время работы: 0:00:00.005998
Исходный размер массива: 14520
Финальный размер массива: 7260
===============================
Создание структуры без None
Время работы: 0:00:00.003000
Исходный размер массива: 14520
Финальный размер массива: 7260
```

2 Запуск:

```
Используем итератор
Время работы: 0:00:00.001004
Исходный размер массива: 14520
Финальный размер массива: 7260
===============================
Используем try-except
Время работы: 0:00:00.005998
Исходный размер массива: 14520
Финальный размер массива: 7260
===============================
Создание структуры без None
Время работы: 0:00:00.003001
Исходный размер массива: 14520
Финальный размер массива: 7260
```

3 Запуск:

```
Используем итератор
Время работы: 0:00:00.001999
Исходный размер массива: 14520
Финальный размер массива: 7260
===============================
Используем try-except
Время работы: 0:00:00.006002
Исходный размер массива: 14520
Финальный размер массива: 7260
===============================
Создание структуры без None
Время работы: 0:00:00.004998
Исходный размер массива: 14520
Финальный размер массива: 7260
```

При этом если создавать новую структуру, мы будем иметь не только массив new_list с размером 59736 байта а еще и создавать временный массив list_not_none с размером в 75672 байта.
Оно нам надо?

Answer (score 2):

почему бы не использовать `filter`:

```
a = [None, None, 8, None,6, None, None, 9, None, None, None, 3, None]
print(sum(filter(None,a)))  # 26
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто используем map и sum:

```py
a = [4, 4, None, 5]
print(sum(map(lambda x: x or 0, a)))
# 13
```

Или задействуем reduce:

```py
from functools import reduce 

a = [4, 4, None, 5]
print(reduce(lambda x,y: x + (y or 0), a))
# 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Полно вариантов, но добавлю ещё один короткий, хотя эти идеи по отдельности уже были в других вариантах:

```
lst = [1, None, 2, 3, 4, None, 6]
print(sum(x or 0 for x in lst))
```

Данный код заменит значения `0` и `None` на `0` перед суммированием.